# http put gives error "type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,

Tags: flutter, http

```
Future<bool> updateProfile(UpdateProfileModel data, String token) async {
Map<String, dynamic> profData = {
  "nickname": data.nickname,
  "firstname": data.firstname,
  "lastname": data.lastname,
  "middlename": data.middlename,
  "aboutMe": data.aboutMe,
  "dateOfBirth": data.dateOfBirth,
  "showDateOfBirth": data.showDateOfBirth,
  "gender": data.gender,
  "regionId": data.regionId,
  "telegram": data.telegram,
  "instagram": data.instagram,
  "facebook": data.facebook,
  "linkedin": data.linkedin,
  "picture": data.picture
};

try {
  String tok = 'Bearer $token';
  Response response = await put(
    Uri.parse(AppUrl.updateProfile),
    body: jsonEncode(profData),
    headers: {'Authorization': tok},
  );
  print(token);`enter code here
  print(jsonEncode(profData));

  print(response.statusCode);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
    print(response.body);
    // var prof = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map;
    return responseData['succeeded'];
  } else {
    return false;
  }
} catch (e) {
  return false;
}
```

}
{"nickname":"john","firstname":"Zhan","lastname":"Tuleu","middlename":null,"aboutMe":"strinasdasdasd","dateOfBirth":"2022-07-21T21:50:52.753","showDateOfBirth":true,"gender":1,"regionId":1,"telegram":"string","instagram":"string","facebook":"string","linkedin":"string","picture":null}

Answer (score 0):

[Answer] I just needed to add that headers,

```
headers: {
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "content-type":"application/json"
}
```